# How to type destructured object key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

Let's say I have query parameter from router in Next.js

```
const {
    query: { id },
  } = useRouter();
```

This  `{ id }` is `string | string[] | undefined`.

I need to pass it as parameter to another function, and I know that it will be a `string` when I will execute a function where `id` is needed.

How can I make `id as string` in destructuring?

Comment: Pass `id ?? ''` to the function. And if you're going to cast whenever the compiler tells you your code is wrong, why are you bothering with TS at all?

Comment: Because I use React Query, and I execute this function with ```enabled: Boolean(id)```, so no way it will fall in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the question is "How can I use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)?"

If that's right, then you must use the assertion after the right-side expression value. Using the code in your question:

What you currently have:

```ts
import { useRouter, type NextRouter } from 'next/router';

const { query: { id } } = useRouter();
               //^? const id: string | string[] | undefined
```

How to use the type assertion:

```ts
import { useRouter, type NextRouter } from 'next/router';

const { query: { id } } = useRouter() as NextRouter & { query: { id: string } };
               //^? const id: string
```

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBKFk3VAGjhgE8x04A5dADxm13zgF84AzKCEOAcgDtaMAPSdGUHgG4AUFIQyAxhD6p4SAI7J8JAFyI4wACYtjAXhQYGeKAAoAlNLiOnzl0KEA9APwzmMuVMVlVTgNLV0kQ2NWMzQsHCs7OABDVCpBSyYAMj1QqB09Q10VKGA+AHMohxdqpzcvHykgA)

---

However, it's safer not to assume and assert, but to actually check at runtime:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMBKFk3VOAXzgDMoIQ4ByAO3QA8YB6c3fKgbgCguBjCGqnhIAjsnwBPAFyI4wACZElAXhQZsbKAAoAlNzgHDR40yYA9APw9gJOFpgSw6CLYVxlH6kKjAaAcyodRC4DUzgAOQgAdzgJHDheAEMaOAAjdASBEgV0GngYAAtE+GAYKlQ4KHREgBsaiThEuG9fPwA6ELgwgBEIOELWiqjSgv6CjJb-OHGqjoMFblNLLkIudBqMYNCmOABJMor0EfxGlMSoKESG6BQaeXRsunk5rp2ACWT5GozC4oTEzYzdAvBZcJZWQhAA)

```ts
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const { query: { id } } = useRouter();
               //^? const id: string | string[] | undefined

if (typeof id === 'string') {
  // Now you can be confident that it's really a string.
  // Do things with the string here.
  id;
//^? const id: string
}
else {
  // It's either an array or undefined.
  // Handle that case here.
  id;
//^? const id: string[] | undefined
}
```

See also: [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) in the TS handbook